# How to secure API server deployed in a DigitalOcean's droplet using HTTPS?

Tags: django, ssl, https, digital-ocean

I have a project hosted on *DigitalOcean* and at the moment I have these clusters:

[image]

My webpage (hosted in the wordpress droplet) is already secured through a SSL certificate and I can publicly access it via https://www.domain_name.it.
However, my mobile application interacts with my Python Django API server that is deployed in the docker-ubuntu-droplet.
An example of API resource that the mobile app uses is **http**://docker_droplet_IP:/api/get-customers/

I would like to secure API calls, such that the mobile application can use HTTPS protocol to safely transfer data (i.e. **https**://docker_droplet_IP:/api/get-customers/) but I am struggling finding out a way to do this, considering that the API server is called directly using the IP address.

Can someone explain me how to proceed (and which steps should I make) to secure my Django API server?

Thank you in advance.